# cv2.cornersSubPix gives only None

Tags: python, opencv

I have no idea, why this openCV function gives me values of None, have any body some thoughts?

```
while True:


    retval,frame = capture.read()
    h, w = frame.shape[:2]
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)
    found, points = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, p_size)


       if found!=0:
        frame_count = frame_count + 1 
        objpoints.append(objp)
        corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, points, (11, 11), (-1,1), criteria)
        imgpoints.append(corners2) </i>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you check out the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=cornersubpix#cv2.cornerSubPix) about `cv2.cornerSubPix`, you can see that it returns None. Actually it modifies the array of corners passed as the argument.

```
cv2.cornerSubPix(image, corners, winSize, zeroZone, criteria) → None
```

Comment: A note for the future. It seems that starting from OpenCV 3.0 `cv2.cornerSubPix` will return `corners` rather than `None`: [http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#cornersubpix)

Both versions of the docs are now online so some users may be confused.